# How to create dynamic checkboxes using a list of objects in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have an object with this attributes: Id, name and status, and I have a List of this object. I want to save the status (enable or disable) for each element.

Comment: Use `<ui:repeat>` bound to your `List`.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Either it's more complicated than what you're describing, or it's extremely fundamental. Look at this [Primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml) that uses `<f:selectItems>`. Maybe Luiggi's idea is better, but it's hard to say: your question is very vague.

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectMultipleRows

Answer (score 2):

You can use SelectManyCheckbox Primefaces Component.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="checkboxTest" value="#{myBean.selectedElements}">

    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myElements}" var="elem" itemLabel="#{elem.value}" itemValue="#{elem.id}" />

</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

You need to create in your backing bean a list that will be filled by the selected element (selectedElements in the example above) and use your list of object (myElements) to create the checkbox on the page. In this way on submit you will have the "selectedElements" list filled with the checked items.

**See more:**

- [Primefaces ManyCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml)

Answer (score 2):

here is a general example (using `<h:dataTable...>`):

**XHTML:**

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable var="row" value="#{categoryMan.items}">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.enabled}">
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.id}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.name}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:commandButton action="#{categoryMan.save}" value="Save">
                </h:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**YourBean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="categoryMan")
@SessionScoped
public class CategoryManager implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8453216983786165042L; 
    private List<Category> items;   
    public CategoryManager() {

    }
    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        try{
            this.items = new ArrayList<Category>();
            this.items.add(new Category("PS2001", "JSF", false));
            this.items.add(new Category("PS2002", "ASP", true));
            this.items.add(new Category("PS2002", "PHP", false));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String save() {
        for(Category cat: this.items){
            System.out.println(cat.getName()+": "+cat.isEnabled());
        }
        return "yourNavigationRule";
    }
    public List<Category> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<Category> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }   
}
```

**Your Object:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Category implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8070175380194294502L;
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean enabled;    
    public Category(String id, String name, boolean enabled) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }   
}
```

Comment: DownVote without any Comments? why?

Comment: No need to downvote this answer. check boxes and items can come in various flavors. This examples explains if when the items you want to display have a boolean property that indicates whether its selected or not.

Another flavor can be if your items doesnt have that boolean property, so you have to get the selected items and put in a list

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have displayed the list of dynamic checkboxes with specific question.

```
                    <p:row styleClass="ui-panelgrid-cell" rowspan="3">
                        <p:column>
                            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">                              
                                <p:dataTable var="tQuestions"
                                    value="#{userPreferences.availableQuestions}"
                                    emptyMessage="No Questions Found." id="sTable">
                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:outputText id="sName" styleClass="cellLabelMand"
                                             value="#{tQuestions.shortText}" />
                                    <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />                                              
                                            <ui:repeat var="tCategoryList" value="#{tQuestions.categoryList}">
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="checked" />
                                            <h:outputText value="#{tCategoryList.categoryValue}" />
                                            </ui:repeat>                                                 
                                    </p:column>                                                                 
                                    </p:dataTable>                              
                            </div>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
```